# WkWebview flashs white when gesture go back/forward

Tags: ios, swift, vue.js, webview, wkwebview

I am making an iOS app with WkWebview, Vue.js.
The website's theme is always dark mode, so every background color is dark `#181818`.

When the gesture go back/forward, the screen show before/next page's preview, right?
Sometimes it doesn't show anything. (I think it is related to cache or SPA)

It doesn't matter. It loads page well finally.

But in WkWebview, the background flashes white when go back/forward.
[webview screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8KsL.png)

I thought html's body color is white, but it was `#181818` too.

[safari screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqFyO.png)

In the safari, it shows `#181818` well..

How can I fix it?

ViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

func hexStringToUIColor (hex:String) -> UIColor {
    var cString:String = hex.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).uppercased()
    
    if (cString.hasPrefix("#")) {
        cString.remove(at: cString.startIndex)
    }
    
    if ((cString.count) != 6) {
        return UIColor.gray
    }
    
    var rgbValue:UInt64 = 0
    Scanner(string: cString).scanHexInt64(&rgbValue)
    
    return UIColor(
        red: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
        green: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
        blue: CGFloat(rgbValue & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
        alpha: CGFloat(1.0)
    )
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate, WKScriptMessageHandler {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!
    var webView: WKWebView!
    
    
    var baseURL = "http://example.com"
    
    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        
        containerView.backgroundColor = hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#121212")
        containerView.isOpaque = false
        
        let contentController = WKUserContentController()
        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        
   
        config.userContentController = contentController
        config.preferences.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
        
        webView = WKWebView(frame: self.containerView.frame, configuration: config)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        webView.isOpaque = false
        webView.isHidden = false
        webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
        webView.scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
        webView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        webView.scrollView.backgroundColor = hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#121212")
        webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
        
        self.view.addSubview(webView)
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.view.isOpaque = false
        self.containerView.isOpaque = false
        webView.isOpaque = false
        
        let backgroundColor = hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#121212")
        webView.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let url = URL(string:baseURL)
        openApp(url: url!)
//        webView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "URL", options: .new, context: nil)
    }
    
    func openApp(url: URL){
        let request = URLRequest(url: url, cachePolicy: URLRequest.CachePolicy.useProtocolCachePolicy)
        webView.evaluateJavaScript("navigator.userAgent") { [weak webView] (result, error) in
            if let webView = webView, let userAgent = result as? String {
                let currentVersion = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String
                
                webView.customUserAgent = userAgent + "ios/" + currentVersion!
            }
        }
        
        webView.load(request)
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you set appearance key in info plist as dark?

Comment: I set <key>UIUserInterfaceStyle</key>
 <string>Dark</string>

Comment: Can you please mention in which OS you are checking this?

Comment: Moreover you can also try below code for iOS 13 and above.                                       ```                                                                     if #available(iOS 13.0, *) { UIWindow.appearance().overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light }                             ```

Comment: @amisolani Deployment target is "iOS 14.1" and I tested with iPhone 12 (14.4), iPhone 8 (14.4). also I did your code in Appdelegate.swift but It doesn't change

Comment: @Kwon 
I have the same problem. did you find a solution?
In the worst case scenario, I will have to take snapshots of the wkwebview while navigating and put them under wkwebview, and turn off the webview navigation, and use native backwipes. I would hate to do that.

Comment: @РоманСергеевич Since I don't have a dummy URL to replicate the issue and try, can you please try without giving isOpaque or giving isOpaque = true.

Comment: @Antony This is not the point at all. There is a general problem that does not depend on the code. I have such a problem in Cordova. in Safari mobile, at some point, if we make more than 6 clicks on links (changing the routing), and then backwipe, we start to see blank screens after 3-4 backswipe. In Safari mobile we see this blank screen in html background color, however in WkWebView this blank screen is always white !!! The question is, how can this be influenced?